# How to add Swagger to Api Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

I have a api gateway on springboot 3.1.4 version. And I have diferents microservices registered on it and they have its own swagger documentation. I need that when I access the api gateway I can see the swagger of the registered microservices on it.

I have tried to registed the swagger route on the api gateway but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please [edit] your question and add some more details. as your question stands, there is not enough information to provide an answer.